# Google Play Services breaks GSM network

Tags: android, google-play-services

Update of Google Play Services is required for hangouts, google+ and other apps. But Google Play Services (8.4.89) breaks GSM network, with this errors:

> E/WifiManager(2841): mWifiServiceMessenger == null
>   **E/MPlugin(2947): Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport**
>   E/WifiManager(2947): mWifiServiceMessenger == null
>   E/MPlugin(1814): Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   E/GmsWearableNodeHelper(1814): GoogleApiClient connection failed:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null,
>   message=null} 03-02 16:51:54.329: E/MPlugin(2878): Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
>   E/ReceiverController(803): filterReceiver() ignored with null action
>   03-02 16:51:54.676: E/ReceiverController(803): filterReceiver()
>   ignored with null action
>   E/BaseAppContext(2878):
>   Tried to stop global GMSCore RequestQueue. This is likely unintended,
>   so ignoring. 
>   E/MPlugin(1814): Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 03-02 16:51:56.209:
>   E/MPlugin(3054): Unsupported class:
>   com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport 03-02 16:51:56.285:
>   E/Babel_SMS(3054): canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc  03-02
>   E/Babel_SMS(3054): canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc
>   nullnull 
>   E/SQLiteLog(3054): (284) automatic index
>   on conversation_participants_view(conversation_id) 03-02 16:51:56.910:
>   E/SQLiteLog(3054): (284) automatic index on

After update Google Play Services with Google Market, GSM does not have any coverage, and no SIM is present (according to Android).
Mobile is Dual SIM based on Mediatek 6735 with Android 5.1
Uninstalling Google Play Services updates, and rebooting GSM works again.
A possible workaround, reboot with original Google Play Services, and after this install Google Play Services updates.

Google Play Services bug, incompatible device, ...?

Comment: Did you find answer for it ?